# くれてやる/くれてあげる meaning

Tags: word-choice

I get that くれてやる・くれてあげる means "I'll give you" from an anime. To be frank, I have no idea how it translates to that. In fact, I didn't even know such a word is possible. くれる is receiving something whilst あげる is giving something. How is it even possible to combine them both?

Comment: I've never encountered くれてあげる. Do you have a real example?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this interesting article](http://nihongodaybyday.blogspot.com/2010/08/blog-post_18.html) which breaks down the phrase くれてやる (and the variant くれてあげる).

Basically, the phrase is a kind of stylized version of the ～てやる construction. This construction is used when someone is doing something for a subordinate or someone familiar (手伝っ**てやる** I'll help you). Although the word くれる usually means that someone else gives you something, the dictionaries do list the alternative meaning of 話し手または話題の人物が他者に物を与える (the speaker gives something to someone else). Using that meaning, the contrived phrase is something like `'I'LL GIVE YOU + てやる'`, meaning 'to give' but also containing a sense of superiority/familiarity. It could come across as extremely overbearing and rude, so this phrase is probably not likely to be used beyond the confines of manga pages.

Comment: Sounds to me like くれる can also mean あげる

Comment: @Newbie don’t get them confused!  they’re not the same. くれる mean essentially “give me” and あげる means essentially “i give”. they are directional verbs. the i/me rendering can vary a bit if you’re speaking from someone else’s perspective let’s say.  but generally distinguish them as to who is receiving vs who is giving.